# Split A Vector to Nonoverlapping Sub-Vector with Equal Length in R

Tags: r, vector, split

I want  `R` to split any vector into series of sub-vectors with these conditions:

1. Every sub-vector must have equal length `l`
2. No two (2) sub-vectors must overlap

I tried this:

when  the parent vector `vec` is divisible by sub-vector length `l`

```
vec <- 1:11 # parent vector.
l <- 2 # number of elements that each sub-vector must contain.
blk <- split(vec, ceiling(seq_along(vec) / l))
test <- length(vec) %% l == 0
```

> $`1`
> [1] 1 2

> $`2`
> [1] 3 4

> $`3`
> [1] 5 6

> $`4`
> [1] 7 8

> $`5`
> [1]  9 10

> $`6`
> [1] 11

when  the parent vector `vec` is not divisible by sub-vector length `l`

```
vec <- 1:11 # parent vector.
l <- 3 # number of elements that each sub-vector must contain.
blk <- split(vec, ceiling(seq_along(vec) / l))
test <- length(vec) %% l == 0
```

> $`1`
> [1] 1 2 3

> $`2`
> [1] 4 5 6

> $`3`
> [1] 7 8 9

> $`4`
> [1] 10 11

**What I want**

If the last sub-vector is not up to the set length discard, otherwise include.

**Edit**

```
test <- length(x) %% l == 0
```

I am thinking of a way I can write a conditional statement such that if `test` is `FALSE` discard the last sub-vector but if `test` is `TRUE` include the last subvector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subset the result for the condition `lengths(blk) == l`.

```
vec <- 1:11 # parent vector.
l <- 3 # number of elements that each sub-vector must contain.
blk <- split(vec, ceiling(seq_along(vec) / l))
blk[lengths(blk) == l]
#if(length(blk[length(blk)]) != l) blk[length(blk)] <- NULL #Alternative
#$`1`
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#$`2`
#[1] 4 5 6
#
#$`3`
#[1] 7 8 9
```